# Save result checkboxes checked in form into sqlite database with javascript

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, checkbox

I have a form in my app with several checkboxen. I want the result(value) of the checked checkedboxes saved into separate rows in the database, see below. The problem is that when saving, only the first one (Ma) is saved and the other ones not eventhough the are checked in the form. When MA is not checkend nothing happens at all... I use JqueryMobile/JavaScript/PhoneGap Build

Form:

```
<form name="test"> 
<label class="label_check" id="l1" for="ch1">Ma
<input class="custom" type="checkbox" name="checkgroup" id="ch1" value="Ma" />
</label>
<label class="label_check" id="l2" for="ch2">Di
<input class="custom" type="checkbox" name="checkgroup" id="ch2" value="Di" checked />
</label>
<label class="label_check" id="l3" for="ch3">Woe
<input class="custom" type="checkbox" name="checkgroup" id="ch3" value="Woe" />
</label>
<label class="label_check" id="l4" for="ch4">Do
<input class="custom" type="checkbox" name="checkgroup" id="ch4" value="Do" />
</label>
<label class="label_check" id="l5" for="ch5">Vr
<input class="custom" type="checkbox" name="checkgroup" id="ch5" value="Vr" checked />
</label>
<label class="label_check" id="l6" for="ch6">Za
<input class="custom" type="checkbox" name="checkgroup" id="ch6" value="Za" />
</label>
<label class="label_check" id="l7" for="ch7">Zo
<input class="custom" type="checkbox" name="checkgroup" id="ch7" value="Zo" />
</label>
</form>
</p>
<p>
<input type="button" name="saveData" id="btn1" value="Save" onclick="saveRecordSafety();"/>
```

Javascript:

```
function saveRecordSafety() {
//Write the record to the database
theDBbeter.transaction(insertRecordSafety, onTxErrorB, onTxSuccessB);
}

function insertRecordSafety(txb) {
var elementen = document.getElementsByName ("checkgroup");
var tmpChoise;
for (var r= 0; r < elementen.lenght; r++);
if (elementen[r].checked) {
tmpChoise = elementen[r].value; 
alert(tmpChoise);
var sqlStrB = 'INSERT INTO testSafetyBeter (beter) VALUES (?)';
txb.executeSql(sqlStrB, [tmpChoise], onSqlSuccess, onSqlError);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is because of your for loop being terminated by a semicolon:

```
for (var r= 0; r < elementen.lenght; r++);
```

Try this:

```
function insertRecordSafety(txb) {

var elementen = document.getElementsByName ("checkgroup");
var tmpChoise;

    for (var r= 0; r < elementen.length; r++)
    {
        if (elementen[r].checked) 
        {
            tmpChoise = elementen[r].value; 
            alert(tmpChoise);
            var sqlStrB = 'INSERT INTO testSafetyBeter (beter) VALUES (?)';
            txb.executeSql(sqlStrB, [tmpChoise], onSqlSuccess, onSqlError);
        }
    }
}
```

I've also spaced things out to make it easier to read.

Comment: Hi Damon, thanks for the answer but i'm afraid it doesn't work, I even get no alert from tmpChoise

Comment: @PowerStudio Sorry spotted a syntax error in the loop it should be length not lenght. Corrected the code, have another go?