# Save checked Chechbox into sqlite database with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, checkbox, sqlite

I have a form in my ejs with several checkboxes. In the application the user should be able to choose his interests by checking the checkboxes and this should be saved into a sqlite Database table. 
I'm building the table via bootstrap:

```
db.exec('CREATE TABLE interests(interest text)');
```

(not sure which type to choose, so I set it to "text", but this is probably wrong?).
My Form looks like this

```
<form name="first_steps" action="first_steps" method="post">
  <ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="interesse" value="theater" id="check1">Theater</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="interesse" value="musik" id="check2">Musik</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="interesse" value="party" id="check3">Party</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="interesse" value="sport" id="check4">Sport</label>
    </li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

I found this Article [Save result checkboxes checked in form into sqlite database with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114407/save-result-checkboxes-checked-in-form-into-sqlite-database-with-javascript) and tried to convert this into my server.js

(Something like this

```
app.post('/first_steps', function(req, res) {
var elementen = document.getElementsByName ("interesse");
var tmpChoise;
for (var r= 0; r < elementen.length; r++) {
    if (elementen[r].checked) {
    tmpChoise = elementen[r].value;
    alert(tmpChoise);
    db.run(`INSERT INTO interessen(interesse) VALUES (?)`, [interesse], function(err) {
            return res.redirect('/profil');
        });
  }
 } 
});
```

but this doesn't work. It says "ReferenceError: document is not defined").

Can someone tell me how the right code would look like? I'm a bloody beginner and couldn't really figure anything out.

(Javascript, express, sqlite3, node.js)

Answer (score 0):

Your server.js file should usually work data that has been [posted](https://fullstack-developer.academy/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js/) from your form. Process should look something like:

1. Display front end form
2. Post front end form data to your server
3. Manipulate or work with data on your server
4. Send some response from your server back to the front end.

In your case, instead of trying to look at DOM elements that would result from `document.getElementsByName ("interesse")`, you should probably be working with data stored on `res.body`. So that might look something like:

```
app.post('/first_steps', function(req, res) {
    data = req.body.interesse;
    db.run(`INSERT INTO interessen(interesse) VALUES (?)`, [data], function(err) {
            return res.redirect('/profil');
        });
  }
 } 
});
```

Or something similar. Check out [this](https://fullstack-developer.academy/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js/) article for an example of getting post data, and then look at the data being posted from your form in a console log like

```
 var postBody = req.body;
 console.log(postBody);
```

(That console log output will be in whatever terminal your express server is running in)